Movie with cars, a nice convertible is burned by it's owner stating "sometimes you must kill what you love"
I caught the end of this movie in early 2007 while at a hotel, and it felt like a recent movie.
There were four people in a warehouse, maybe an auto shop.  The four people consisted of: a white female about 30 years old and three teenagers - early twenties. They consisted of a white female, a white male, and a black male.
The lady was being reintroduced to what appears to have been her car, a red 60-70s convertible. but she is upset because the younger people had repainted it.  She forces the young girl to execute the two young males.
The two females drive the car outside to the middle of an empty lot, the lady exclaims "sometimes you must destroy what you love" takes a license plate from a pile of plates in the trunk, douses the car in gas and sets it on fire.
They then steal a 60ish pickup truck from a gas station and are shown changing the plates.  While driving, the driver and passenger come to some understanding that the young girl did not really kill the two boys. If she had the lady said she would have been dead too.
Flashback to the warehouse:  the dead boys sit up, and climb into a different car, which cranks but won't start as the scene fades and the credits roll.
Anyone know what movie this may be?
